# How to show null or zero values in cross/left join MYSQL with BETWEEN DATE condition

Tags: mysql

I have a query that count rows between dates(3 months). It shows me the total rows for each month which have records in that month. But if records in month not exists, the query isn`t showing me the null or zero value.

I've tried left join, cross join, coalesce(t2.id,0) and I'm don't achieve anything.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.month, ' ' , y.years) as month, COUNT(t2.id) as quantity 
FROM 
( SELECT 'Jan' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Feb' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Mar' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Apr' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'May' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Jun' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Jul' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Aug' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Sep' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Oct' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Nov' month UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Dec' month ) t1 CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(data) as years FROM negocio) y 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT id, data FROM negocio) t2 
on t1.month = LEFT(monthname(t2.data), 3) AND y.years = YEAR(t2.data) 
WHERE (t2.data BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND NOW()) 
GROUP BY t1.month, y.years ORDER BY year(STR_TO_DATE(years, '%YYYY')), month(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%M'))
```

What I need is described in this example:

```
|--------------|                        |--------------|
|month|quantity|                        |month|quantity|
|-----|--------|   and it must show ->  |-----|--------|
| Feb |    5   |                        | Feb |    5   |
| Apr |   26   |                        | Mar |    0   |
|--------------|                        | Apr |   26   |
                                        |--------------|
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Move your `WHERE` condition into your `ON` clause i.e. `ON t1.month = LEFT(monthname(t2.data), 3) AND y.years = YEAR(t2.data) 
AND (t2.data BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND NOW())`. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html) about optimization: "For a LEFT JOIN, if the WHERE condition is always false for the generated NULL row, the LEFT JOIN is changed to an inner join."

Comment: I've tried this already. It shows me all months and years. Is not fitering by interval

Comment: Apologies, your question is similar (the `WHERE` condition is why you don't get a row for March), but different. I will reopen.

Comment: We're at May 9th now, do you want all sales for February or just those on or after the 9th of February?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is what is causing you not to get any data in your output for March, as it will fail for any row in `negocio` that has a `NULL` `data` value, thus effectively converting the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` and removing rows for any month which has no values in `negocio` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html)). That condition should be moved to the `ON` condition. You do still need a `WHERE` clause, but it should be on the date generated from `t1` and `y`. I've assumed your requirement on the 9th of May is to count values from the 9th of February onwards, in which case the required condition is:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', y.year, t1.month, DAY(CURDATE())), '%Y-%b-%d') BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND CURDATE()
```

This query should give you the results you want. For ease of ordering and joining to the `negocio` table, I've added a month number field to your months (`t2`) table:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.month, ' ' , y.year) as month, 
       COUNT(t2.id) as quantity
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS mnum, 'Jan' AS month UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 'Feb'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 'Mar'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 'Apr'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 5, 'May'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 6, 'Jun'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 7, 'Jul'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 8, 'Aug'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 9, 'Sep'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 10, 'Oct'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 11, 'Nov'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 12, 'Dec' ) t1 CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(data) AS year FROM negocio) y 
LEFT JOIN negocio t2 ON t1.mnum = MONTH(t2.data) AND y.year = YEAR(t2.data) AND t2.data BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND CURDATE()
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', y.year, t1.month, DAY(CURDATE())), '%Y-%b-%d') BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY y.year, t1.month, t1.mnum
ORDER BY y.year, t1.mnum
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x1QcJVCwT3973yUgzG81qn/0)

Comment: Thank you Nick, this is what I need.